# angular2 - get data from parent directive

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, angular

I have an Form directive and inside a messsage directive to print out data from the form.

Form.html

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form">
      <input ngControl="field">
      <message></message>
</form>
```

Login.js

```
export class Form{
form;

constructor(_form: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = _form.group({
        'field': ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
```

Message.js

```
export class Message {
    constructor() {}

get errorMessage() {
    console.log(form);<--- Here form is needed
}
```

}

What is the best way to access the formModel in the message directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a parameter to your `Message` component using the `@Input` decorator:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class Message {
  @Input()
  form: Control;

  constructor() {}

  get errorMessage() {
    console.log(this.form);
  }
}
```

You can pass the parameter as described below:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form">
  <input ngControl="field">
  <message [form]="form"></message>
</form>
```

Another option would be to inject the parent component into the child one:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class Message {
  constructor(parent:Form) {
    this.form = parent.form;
  }

  (...)
}
```

Comment: I was just typing your 'other option', but that seems futile now :). Well done thierry